# Use Asp.Net Identity to secure WebApi controllers

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am using Asp.Net Identity to secure my application. The configuration for Asp.Net Identity includes a standard call to app.UseCookieAuthentication.

I then have an MVC controller (inheriting from System.Web.Mvc.Controller) secured using System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute and it works perfectly - logged in users can use the MVC controller and anonymous users are not allowed.

I have another controller, this time a WebApi one (inheriting from System.Web.Http.ApiController). I am trying to secure it the same way, i.e. a logged in user (using the MVC login) can call it and an anonymous user cannot. I tried using the same attribute (System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute) but in this case any user (even if not authorized) can call the controller. If I use System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute (which should be the correct one for WebApi controllers) every user (even logged in) gets the error Authorization has been denied for this request.

I suppose I have to somehow configure WebApi to use the same identity as the MVC controllers but I cannot find how. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: Using the System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute and then the HostAuthenticationAttribute with value DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie makes WebApi use the application cookie for calls. The controller looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)]
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    ...
}
```